# Get information about the next video on button video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I cannot insert the information video title the next button. I can not do it and every modification I make stops everything from working.

Example: `<button class="next">Next Adele - Send My Love (To Your New Lover)</button>`

https://jsfiddle.net/bv2Lez10/

> The code is very long and Stack Overflow does not let me finish publishing the question, that's why I add this link.

Comment: To get the song details you will need to some sort of API. For example if the video is a youtube video you can use their API to get the video details.

Comment: Thanks, but not all the videos are from youtube. There are videos that the client already has.

Comment: Which also means you will need to find a way to extract the video data/title... Your question is becoming impossible to answer. Unless you store the video titles in the `videoList` array of objects you currently have I cannot think of any other solution for you.

Comment: Ok thanks you! I'll see how I solve it